# Canvas RenderTransform error "Cannot convert" in VisualStudio 2010 SilverLight 4

Tags: silverlight

```
<Canvas Width="945" Height="718" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Canvas RenderTransform="1.333333333,0,0,1.333333333,0,0" />
</Canvas>
```

This works fine in WPF but the following error in SilverLight

Error   3   Cannot convert "1.333333333,0,0,1.333333333,0,0".

Comment: What does "1.333333333,0,0,1.333333333,0,0" represent? There are differences between WPF and Silverlight that might make a difference here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a `MatrixTransform` to me, create it explicitly using element syntax as there does not appear to be a type converter.

```
<Canvas.RenderTransform>
    <MatrixTransform>
        <MatrixTransform.Matrix>
            <!-- I do not know the WPF parsing order
            so you'll need to find out what goes where yourself -->
            <Matrix OffsetX="???" OffsetY="???"
                    M11="???" M12="???"
                    M21="???" M22="???" />
        </MatrixTransform.Matrix>
    </MatrixTransform>
</Canvas.RenderTransform>
```

---

Testing suggest that this is the respective `Matrix`:

```
<Matrix M11="1.333333333" M22="1.333333333"/>
```